# Font collapsing on pc fine on mac

Tags: css, fonts

[image]the font 'mariadavidregular' is collapsing on a windows machine. It looks fine on a Mac

Visit http://wordpress-24576-52736-156017.cloudwaysapps.com
and you will see the letter 'o's are collapsing and look bad. it also seems to effect the letter to the right of it.

Here is how I include the font.

```
   @font-face {
        font-family: 'maridavidregular';
        src: url('fonts/maridavid-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/maridavid-webfont.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you clarify more.?

Comment: instead of telling people to visit a URL, show screenshots of what you're seeing - and if you do direct people to a URL, make sure it's a proof-of-concept URL that exposes the code/resources you're using, as a [mcve]. Just pointing people to a website and then expecting them to be able to guess what part of it they should be noticing is not [asking a good question](/help/how-to-ask).